# Passing value from one page to another using master pages

Tags: asp.net

my problem is i want to pass value of a label and hidden control which are resides in a datalist say in page1.aspx and i want to access these value in page2.aspx. How can i get the values to another page while clicking on submit button. Is there any better option we have without using sessions, server.transfer, request.querystrings etc. Pls. help. I am using master pages. Can we use previouspage? if so how. Suggest me a better solutions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use `PreviousPage`, by way of a cross-page post.

First, assign the `PostBackUrl` property of an `<asp:Button>` control on the first page to point to the second one.

Next, set the `PreviousPage` directive on the second page:

```
<%@ PreviousPageType VirtualPath="~/first.aspx" %>
```

When the second page receives a postback, get the data you need from the first page:

```
Page previous = Page.PreviousPage;
if (previous != null)
{
    Label label = (Label)previous.FindControl("myLabel");
    if (label != null)
    {
        string text = label.Text;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use a hidden input element, then it's value will be available via `Request.Form`, e.g.

**HTML in Page1.aspx**

```
<input type="hidden" name="country" value="Norway" />
```

**C# in Page2.aspx**

```
var country = Request.Form["country"];  // "Norway"
```

Comment: in the question it is stated that the data is contained in a hidden control/label

Answer (score 0):

You've certainly eliminated a lot of the usual methods of persisting data between pages.  Other than queryString parameters, there are also hidden form values (Adam's example) and cookies which are also accessible from the Request object.  If the data is relatively small and not particularly sensitive, you could write it to a cookie on the user's machine.

Alternately, you'd need some sort of persistence mechanism to hold the data. You could write the information to a file on the web server. The obvious downside is that you need to have more complex logic to ensure that data from each user is kept separate, you'd essentially need to create your own session management logic.

The other option that comes to mind would be persisting the information to a database. Unless you need to store and manage a whole bunch of complex data, this really isn't a viable options in most cases. It also comes with most of the same pitfalls as the file storage mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

Unless performance is a *real* issue, just go with Session.